# Grow a ffdf data frame on disk gradually

Tags: r, ff, ffbase

From documentation of save.ffdf:

> Using ‘save.ffdf’ automagically sets the ‘finalizer’s of the ‘ff’ 
>   vectors to ‘"close"’. This means that the data will be preserved  on
>   disk when the object is removed or the R sessions is closed.  Data can
>   be deleted either using ‘delete’ or by removing the  directory where
>   the object were saved (‘dir’).

I want to starting with a small ffdf data frame, add a bit new data at a time, and grow it on the disk. So I did a little experiment:

```
# in R
ffiris = as.ffdf(iris)
save.ffdf(ffiris, dir = "~/Desktop/iris")

# in bash
ls ~/Desktop/iris/
## ffiris$Petal.Length.ff ffiris$Petal.Width.ff  ffiris$Sepal.Length.ff ffiris$Sepal.Width.ff  ffiris$Species.ff

# in R
# add a new column
ffiris =transform(ffiris, new1 = rep(99, nrow(iris)))
rm(ffiris)

# in bash
ls ~/Desktop/iris/
## ffiris$Petal.Length.ff ffiris$Petal.Width.ff  ffiris$Sepal.Length.ff ffiris$Sepal.Width.ff  ffiris$Species.ff
```

It turns out it doesn't automatically update the ff data on disk when I remove ffiris. What about saving it manually?

```
# in R
# add a new column
ffiris =transform(ffiris, new1 = rep(99, nrow(iris)))
save.ffdf(ffiris, "~/Desktop/iris")

# in bash
ls ~/Desktop/iris/
## ffiris$Petal.Length.ff ffiris$Petal.Width.ff  ffiris$Sepal.Length.ff ffiris$Sepal.Width.ff  ffiris$Species.ff
```

Hmm, still no luck. Why?

What about removing the folder before saving?

```
# in R
ffiris = as.ffdf(iris)
unlink("~/Desktop/iris", recursive = TRUE, force = TRUE)
save.ffdf(ffiris, "~/Desktop/iris", overwrite = TRUE)
ffiris =transform(ffiris, new1 = rep(99, nrow(iris)))
unlink("~/Desktop/iris", recursive = TRUE, force = TRUE)
save.ffdf(ffiris, "~/Desktop/iris", overwrite = TRUE)

# in bash
ls ~/Desktop/iris/
# ls: /Users/ky/Desktop/iris/: No such file or directory
```

Even stranger. 
Even if this all works, it still would be terribly inefficient. I am looking for something like:

```
updateOnDisk(ffiris)
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ff` and `ffbase` offer out of memory R vectors, but introduce a reference semantics which can give problems with R idioms.

R is a functional programming language, meaning that functions do not change parameters and objects, but return modified copies. In `ffbase` we implement functions in the R way, i.e. `transform` returns a copy of the original ffdf `data.frame`. This can be seen by looking at the filenames:

```
ffiris = as.ffdf(iris)
save.ffdf(ffiris, dir = "~/Desktop/iris")
filename(ffiris) # show contents of ~/Desktop/iris

ffiris =transform(ffiris, new1 = 99) # this create a copy of the whole data.frame!
filename(ffiris)  

ffiris$new2 <- ff(rep(99, nrow(iris)))  # this creates a new column, but not yet in the right directory
filename(ffiris)

save.ffdf(ffiris, dir="~/Desktop/iris", overwrite=TRUE) # this fixes that.
```

Transform is currently inefficient to add a new column, because it copies the whole data frame (that is R semantics). This is because transform might be a temparory result and you don't wont to change the original data.

In ffbase2 we are fixing this issue

Comment: In the last line, does `save.ffdf` overwrite all the existing vectors, or just add a new one to the `~/Desktop/iris` folder?